# ASP.NET Core Razor ajax POST request data object is empty

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

There is a simple ajax POST request that must **stringify** a simple class and pass it in the body of POST request, but the **Person** parameter on the server-side has empty(default) values

```js
// javascript
var person = { "FirstName": "Andrew", "LastName": "Lock", "Age": "31" };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/UpdatePostBody?handler=Abc",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(person),
    headers: {
        RequestVerificationToken:
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
    },
})
    .done(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
});
```

```cs
// C# code
public IActionResult OnPostAbc(Person person)
{
    return new JsonResult("my result");
}
```

[image]

On the server-side, there is a simple ASP.NET Core Razor page with a method that gets hit and returns the result but the **person** param members have no values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your Pesron data is null is because your `Age` in class `Person` is **int** type.And your person in `{ "FirstName": "Andrew", "LastName": "Lock", "Age": "31" }` is **string** type,So you cannot get it.Also,as you pass json data from ajax to handler,you need to add `[FromBody]` in handler.Here is a demo:

cshtml:

```
<button onclick="postdata()">Abc</button>
function postdata() {
        //change Age type to int
        var person = { "FirstName": "Andrew", "LastName": "Lock", "Age": 31 };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/UpdatePostBody?handler=Abc",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(person),
            headers: {
                RequestVerificationToken:
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
            },
        })
            .done(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            });
    }
```

cshtml.cs:

```
public IActionResult OnPostAbc([FromBody]Person person)
        {
            return new JsonResult("my result");
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: [FromBody] of course was used, the real problem was the "31" string used instead of an int value, just haven't observed the typo

Answer (score 2):

As you have identified, JSON is sent as part of the request body. You could (as you have done in your own answer) read the input stream and deserialize it manually, but there is a much simpler way using the `[FromBody]` attribute on the handler parameter:

```
public IActionResult OnPostAbc([FromBody] Person person)
{
    return new JsonResult($"my result: {person.FirstName} {person.LastName}");
}
```

However, this only works in 3.1 with the default serializer (System.Text.Json) if you remove the quotes from numbers in your `person` object:

```
var person = { "FirstName": "Andrew", "LastName": "Lock", "Age": 31 };
```

Or if you [add your own type converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1#allow-or-write-numbers-in-quotes).

The previous serializer, JSON.Net, is happy with either version. And quoted numbers [are supported in ASP.NET Core 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#allow-or-write-numbers-in-quotes).

Comment: Thanks but this method does not work :)(I have tried it), maybe because of Razor pages?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a note about quoted numbers

Answer (score 1):

Solved by reading the data from POST body

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAbc()
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024];
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var read = 0;
        while ((read = await Request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var person = 
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.GetBuffer()));
        return new JsonResult($"my result: {person.FirstName} {person.LastName}");
    }
}
```